# Iptables - Does local traffic go through the input and output chains?

Tags: iptables

Let's say I have two physical interfaces eth1 and eth2.

eth1 has assigned 192.168.0.1

eth2 has assigned 192.168.0.2

One local process listens on 192.168.0.2 and another local process connects from 192.168.0.1.

Does the ip package go through the OUTPUT and INPUT chains of iptable, or is there some sort of short circuit?
Does it go through the FORWARD chain?

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ip+tables+chart&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @jstola I've looked at most of those already. I feel most of them imply there is no short circuit for local delivery, but it seems plausible that it's just left out for brevity.

Comment: I do not know the answer ... you could add logging to see the packets traversing through

Comment: What is also useful fact to know but was not asked is that traffic goes through the `lo` (loopback) interface, not through eth1 or eth2.

Comment: Also, if you're using any kind of VM or container in your experiment, then it's a completely different case, and it does matter to state if that would be the case.

Comment: @A.B re. lo: My loopback device only has 127.0.0.1/8 assigned. Would the packets end up on the loopback device even if the source and destination addresses are both in the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traffic follows the routes in place.

So how to know which it will be? By checking the route. Here it's from an address belonging to the host to an address belonging to the host. This always results in choosing the `lo` (loopback) interface, because there's no need to involve any NIC hardware in such case:

If the client really binds to 192.168.0.1 first (it's rarely done):

```
$ ip route get from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.2
local 192.168.0.2 from 192.168.0.1 dev lo uid 1000 
    cache <local>
```

Usually this happens (but it's the same overall result):

```
$ ip route get to 192.168.0.2
local 192.168.0.2 dev lo src 192.168.0.2 uid 1000 
    cache <local>
```

To emphasis the conclusion of this result: such traffic *never* uses `eth0` or `eth1` but will use `lo`.

It's useful to know how Netfilter (and thus *iptables*) works along the network stack (and here the routing stack part):

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]
<sup>By [Jan Engelhardt](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Jengelh) - Own work, Origin [SVG](http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.svg) [PNG](http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png), [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=8575254)</sup>

A local application will emit a packet: that's the filter/OUTPUT chain. It also traverses other chains (other OUTPUT and then POSTROUTING chains), but let's just stick to the filter table. This packet is looped back: that's the special property of the `lo` interface. It arrives as if it were a new packet in the routing stack, thus follows PREROUTING  treatment (but PREROUTING chains don't hook with the filter table) gets a routing decision: it's a local destination packet, so also follows the INPUT branch. Packet arrives at the target application.

A standard Linux stateful firewall based on *iptables* uses at least the following rules (I'm using `-I` + number to force the order of rules, normally `-A` is used):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate established,related -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

and then usually its policy is set to DROP:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

The second rule, while it could be considered a security weakness for some kind of environments is very often present and needed, because many applications which expect to be able to communicate over the loopback interface can fail without it.

So any rule needing to prevent such use should be inserted before this second rule. Also any rule based on interface and not on the address on this interface will fail to address the local case.

So if this second rule is deleted:

```
iptables -D INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

then for example to allow an exception for the HTTP service which works with OP's example:

1. wrong (never matches for OP's case):

   ```
   iptables -I INPUT 2 -i eth2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
   ```
2. acceptable:

   ```
   iptables -I INPUT 2 -d 192.168.0.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
   ```
3. also acceptable (and often done like this):

   ```
   iptables -I INPUT 2 -i lo -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I INPUT 3 -i eth2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
   ```

Note that it's not completely equivalent. For example a client coming from the `eth1` side can't access the HTTP service with case 3, while it could access it with case 2. Likewise if the listening service listens on INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) rather than just 192.168.0.2, accessing 127.0.0.1 doesn't work in case 2. but works in case 3.

Comment: Than you for the thorough answer. 
Would the traffic also go on lo if the source and destination were on different subnets? E.g. 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.2.1/24. And would it in that case pass through filter/forward at some point(even if it's on lo)?

Comment: What matters is if the addresses belong to the system or don't belong to the system. And if the packet doesn't *traverse* the system without starting or stopping at it, then it's routed and follows the FORWARD chain. In  cases (like the content of your question) where the packet starts or ends at the system, FORWARD is not involved.